# Jeep Wrangler Sahara engine swap

Tags: jeep, engine-swap

My friend is selling his 2000 Jeep Wrangler Sahara 3960cc car at a good price. I was wondering if is possible to swap the petrol engine with a 2007 Jeep Patriot 2.0 CRD engine. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to replace a 3.9l with a 2.0l engine? I can understand going the other way, but halving your displacement and power doesn't seem like a winner to me.

Comment: @GdD - I believe the 4-cyl the OP is talking about is diesel, which has tons of low end torque, which is good for out-in-the-woods action. As well, the diesel gets a lot better fuel mileage. If this is the OPs intent, the swap is actually a very good idea.

Comment: That makes more sense @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. Would you be able to keep the existing transfer case?

Comment: @GdD - *Maybe?* It depends. I believe the engine the OP is talking about putting into the vehicle is produced by VW, which may limit its interchangeability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Yes but it depends on many things:

if you expect to just remove and refit then no

But if you plan to change the complete drivetrain, manufacture engine mounts, gearbox mounts, new driveshafts and convert or adapt all the sensors required and deal with the ecu issues etc then yes.

You will likely need a full workshop and all the skills.

I have done this type of thing twice (v8 replacing 4cylinder and turbo diesel replacing 4cyl petrol), and it is not easy, but fun if you have the skills and knowledge.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you for your answer! A bit strange dropping to a 2litre 4cyl diesel but the fuel economy is fantastic! Take care